# quad and trapz integrations return very different values

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I want to use quad instead of trapz to make a more officiant code, but quad returns a very different value an also says "IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved...". here is the code:

```
def delta_t(m_lens,z_lens,y_impact):
return 4*const.G*const.c**-3*m_lens*const.M_sun*(1+z_lens)*(0.5*y_impact*np.sqrt(y_impact**2+4)+np.log((np.sqrt(y_impact**2+4)+y_impact)/(np.sqrt(y_impact**2+4)-y_impact)))

def y_max(r_max):
y_max = np.sqrt((1+r_max)/r_max**0.5-2)
return y_max

def y_min(m_lens,z_lens,dt_min):
y_min = fsolve(lambda y: delta_t(m_lens, z_lens, y) - dt_min*u.s, 0)[0]
return y_min

def cosmo_dependent_part(z_lens,z_source,f_dm):
cosmo_dependent_part = 3/2*f_dm*0.24/const.c*((cosmo.WMAP9.H0*1000*u.meter/u.kilometer)**2*cosmo.WMAP9.angular_diameter_distance_z1z2(0,z_lens)*cosmo.WMAP9.angular_diameter_distance_z1z2(z_lens,z_source))/(cosmo.WMAP9.H(z_lens)*1000*u.meter/u.kilometer*cosmo.WMAP9.angular_diameter_distance_z1z2(0,z_source))
return cosmo_dependent_part
```

first integral:

```
def optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand(z_source,z_lens,f_dm,m_lens,dt_min,r_max):
return cosmo_dependent_part(z_lens,z_source,f_dm)*(1+z_lens)**2*(y_max(r_max)**2-y_min(m_lens,z_lens,dt_min)**2)

def optical_depth_fixed_source(z_source,f_dm,m_lens,dt_min,r_max):
    z_lens_array = np.linspace(0,z_source,100)
    optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand_array=np.array([optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand(z_source,z_lens,f_dm,m_lens,dt_min,r_max) for z_lens in z_lens_array])
    optical_depth_fixed_source = integrate.trapz(optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand_array,z_lens_array)
    return optical_depth_fixed_source
print(optical_depth_fixed_source(1,1,30,1e-3,5))
```

the output:

```
0.017963036494289607
```

the second integral:

```
def optical_depth_fixed_source0(z_source,f_dm,m_lens,dt_min,r_max):
optical_depth_fixed_source0 = integrate.quad(optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand,0,z_source,args=(z_source,f_dm,m_lens,dt_min,r_max))[0]
return optical_depth_fixed_source0
print(optical_depth_fixed_source0(1,1,30,1e-3,5))
```

second output:

```
-5.17389415131513
C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:2: IntegrationWarning: The maximum number of subdivisions (50) has been achieved.
  If increasing the limit yields no improvement it is advised to analyze 
  the integrand in order to determine the difficulties.  If the position of a 
  local difficulty can be determined (singularity, discontinuity) one will 
  probably gain from splitting up the interval and calling the integrator 
  on the subranges.  Perhaps a special-purpose integrator should be used.
```

what is "special-purpose integrator" and how do I do it?

I've tried splitting the quad integral over smaller segments but it didn't help.

what else can I try?

how can I increase the limit?

I couldn't minimize the code so I added all of it

Comment: is there anything I can do to improve the question so that I might get an answer? I really need help

Comment: You should provide a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could reproduce the reported behavior. You are missing a simplified version of the function being integrated that results in the same behaviour (or a complete version, if a simplification is not feasible) or a sample of the values it generates.

Comment: From the first example I see that you're integrating over the `z_lens` space, right? However `z_lens` is the second argument of the function you like to integrate. `integrate.quad()` assumes the that the first parameter of the function you pass to it is the variable over which you like to integrate. Try chancing the order of the arguments in `optical_depth_fixed_source_integrand`, s.t. `z_lens` is first.

Comment: It fixed it!!! thank you very much!!! :)